# How to overcome "(FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted" error in awk

Tags: awk

I have a 10 column text file and I need to do some mathematical processing on it.
For example, when I issue below command

```
cat case.dat | awk '{print ($1-0.777472), ($1*$2*$3*$4)/($10)}'
```

Then I get below error

```
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted
```

and the script does not give any output.

That means I have some `zero's` in `$8` and thus I am getting error. How I can overcome this issue with a simple awk command?

Comment: `/($10)` and `I have some zero's in $8` why in `$8`? `How I can overcome this` Don't do it? How do you _want_ to "overcome" it?

Comment: That 10 was a number to multiply. I have updated it to avoid any confusion

Comment: It is not printing any value and the command fails with the mention error.

Comment: What value do you want to print when `$10` is zero?

Comment: I want it to be zero

Comment: Use `awk '{print ($1-0.777472), ($10 ? ($1*$2*$3*$4)/$10 : 0)}' case.dat`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

In order to avoid `fatal: division by zero` error have a check if `$10` is non-zero before attempting to divide:

```sh
awk '{print ($1-0.777472), ($10 ? ($1*$2*$3*$4)/$10 : 0)}' case.dat
```